# How to listen soft keyboard's state changed event?

Tags: android, keyboard-events

help,Android question:I hava to listen soft keyboard's state changed event ,but I could'nt find some api to use ?So , asking for help here,thanks..

Comment: WHat soft keyboard changed event?  Unless you can describe it better, my answer is "it doesn't exist".  If you mean the soft keyboard being opened-  it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
public void setListenerToRootView() {
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener globalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int height = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
            if (height > 100) {
                isKeyboardVisible = true;
                keyboardHeight = height;
            } else {
                isKeyboardVisible = false;
                difHeight = height;
            }
        }
    };
    activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(globalLayoutListener);
}
```